# Temporarily Stop R From Recording History

Tags: r, rstudio

I find it very useful, in general, for my R history to be saved. I refer to it weekly, or more. Exploratory work in the console gradually gets refined and added to a file.

Occasionally a command will have a secret in it like an API key or searching a dataframe with confidential info, in which case I would like to be able to disable history being saved just for that one command and re-enable it immediately after. Something as much like bash's [`ignorespace`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces) option as possible.

I would be happy for a solution that worked in either R or RStudio, both would be even better. I know history can be manually disabled by going to `Tools > Options > General > Always save history` but I'm looking for either a command (or keyboard shortcut) so it can be turned on or off quickly.

Edit: something I thought might work but seemed not to help at all was settling "R_HISTFILE" to FALSE or a non-existent file. It doesn't to help the RStudio history at least. My examination of what it actually did has not been very thorough yet.

Comment: it does not turn off logging, but have you considered one of these options? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/secrets.html.

Comment: @BigDataScientist thank you that does work for the API key use case and has a lot of great general advice, but it would be really good to have something quicker for the case of ad-hoc searching by sensitive data.

Comment: i am not sure this will work with the current version of RStudio, see the links in the paragraph "Concerning the confidential info:" of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i stated in the comment, there are ways to avoid having an API key stored in the history file. As the comment seemed to have collected some upvotes it might be worth the effort to expand it in an answer.

> Occasionally a command will have a secret in it like an API key or searching a dataframe with confidential info, in which case I would like to be able to disable history being saved just for that one command and re-enable it immediately after.

I think right now, it is only possible to find a sultion for the "API key issue" with the current version of RStudio, see the comments in the links of paragraph: "Concerning the confidential info:"

However, while waiting for a soultion this page could be of interest for you: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/secrets.html.

Avoid having the API key stored is easier than the confidential info of a data.frame i think.

**Concerning the confidential info:**

Longer to introduce, but "clean":
I think its worth to add it as a feature request for the great `rstudioapi` package or adding up here:

- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000932128-RStudio-Config-Files
- Related: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1607 (would enable user to write their own addin)
- Related: https://community.rstudio.com/t/configure-rstudio-global-options-on-install/14881 (would enable user to write their own addin)

Fast to introduce, but dirty:
- a hacky dirty workaround would be to introduce an add-in to delete the last insert in the history file.

**Information storage**

Here is described where the settings are stored: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State.

You can navigate to the Rstudio-desktop folder. E.g. on windows enter: %localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop in the explorer.

The global options you are looking for can be found here: ..\monitored\user-settings\user-settings.

The flag "always save history,..." in Rstudio - Tools - Global Options - General is the first value in ..\monitored\user-settings\user-settings.

Unfortunately, RStudio won´t listen on changes in that file, so you would have to restart RStudio to make changes be visible. So for now it is not an option for temporarily stopping Rstudio from recording the history.

**Concerning the API key**, let me summarize a few approaches of that page:

- Add a "popup" to ask for the secret: rstudioapi::askForPassword()
- use environmental variables. You avoid the popup, but i think it just moves the logging of the confidential info from the "history" to the envar.
- finally see the [keyring](https://github.com/r-lib/keyring) package for storing the data in the secret store of your OS.

Comment: I'm going to give this another day or so, in case some wizard who only logs on every other Wednesday knows a secret.

Comment: just in case you are interested i just found where the info about history logging is stored. I made an edit, see "Information storage". Wont solve the issue, but might be interesting to know,...